# UITextView text alignment in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` to get numbers input from user when user set focus on `UITextView` then text in `textview` goes upward. I want to set it horizontally center. Can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center  //swift

Comment: @jamil65able that will center horizontally. The question asks for vertical centering.

Comment: @jamil65able This code is not working. You can get idea from the image above.

Comment: you mention upper text view?

Comment: text view has no such property. so you have to acheieve this by  a tricky

Comment: @jamil65able Yes. TextView with 'America' text. I want to set it horizontal center.

Comment: Any way to set it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a little tricky fix. You would need to observe `contentSize` property of your `UITextView` and then adjust its `contentSize` & `contentOffset` like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [self.textView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)iKeyPath ofObject:(id)iObject change:(NSDictionary *)iChange context:(void *)iContext {
    UITextView *myTextView = (UITextView *)iObject;
    CGFloat topCorrect = (myTextView.bounds.size.height - [myTextView contentSize].height * [myTextView zoomScale]) / 2.0;
    topCorrect = (topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect);
    myTextView.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
}
```